# mousemove jquery сбор положения мышки каждые 2 минуты

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).movemouse(function(e){
        console.log("X: " + e.pageX+" Y: "+e.pageY);
    })
})
```

Мне нужно, чтобы на консоль выводились координаты каждые 2 минуты, а не всё время при передвижении мыши. Возможно ли это и в какую сторону копать?

Я пробовал `setInterval()`, но так ничего и не добился.

**Вторая попытка:**

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    var x=50;
    var y = 100;
    $(this).mousemove( function(e){
        x = e.pageX;
        y = e.pageY;
        setInterval( function(){
            console.log(x,y);
        }, 5000);
    })
})
```

Comment: Я поменял немного код, но переменная выводится на консоль все равно множество раз, это из за многопоточности ? Возможно ли как-нибудь с этим справиться?
`$(document).ready(function(){
  var x=50;
  var y = 100;
 $(this).mousemove(function(e){
  x = e.pageX;
  y = e.pageY;
  setInterval(function(){
   console.log(x,y);
  },5000);
 })
 
})`

Comment: функция внутри mousemove выполняется часто-часто при движении мышкой. И каждый раз запускает свой интервал – у вас возникают сотни веток таймеров. Нет, JS пока не многопоточный в общем случае.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Положение мышки можно получать только из мышиных событий, напр., `mousemove`. Поэтому пускай слушатель этого события работает постоянно, но не выводит сразу же в консоль, а просто обновляет переменную. А по таймеру выводите в консоль значение этой переменной раз в 2 минуты.

P.S. `jQuery` для этого совсем не обязательна – вам ведь нужно только слушать событие документа `mousemove`, обновлять переменную и `setInterval()`.

---

Как-то так:

```js
var myMouse = { x: null, y: null }; // тут держим координаты

function mouseMoved(e) {  // обновляет координаты в переменной выше
  myMouse.x = e.pageX;
  myMouse.y = e.pageY;
}

function mouseDisplay() { // выводит из переменной, что там есть
  document.body.innerHTML += '<br>' + myMouse.x +':'+ myMouse.y;
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoved); // слушаем событие
window.setInterval( mouseDisplay, 1200); // запускаем таймер
```